# How to do button click in code (not by mouse) in LINQPad?

Tags: javascript, c#, linqpad

Is it possible to trigger a button click event in code? either in C# or JavaScript.

[image]

**Edit:**
here is the body part of html being generated, the button's id (**EL2**) is not stable. every time I click run (or F5), the Id will add 1.

```
<body><div id='final'><div><button id="EL2">OK</button></div></div></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
btn.HtmlElement.InvokeMethod (false, "click");
```

(In LINQPad 5.41 or earlier, omit the `false` argument.)

The HtmlElement property also lets you access the auto-generated ID (`HtmlElement.ID`). The `ID` property is writable so you can explicitly assign it if you prefer it not to be auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

In JS following code should work:

document.getElementById("elementID").click();

Comment: here is the html being generated, <button id="EL14">OK</button> the issue is, id keeps changing, each time I click run (or F5), the Id will add 1.

Comment: Can you upload a bit of a html generated code? We can also use technique such as last child in a parent element or something similar.